How to achieve fortran numerical results reproducibility across different platforms (Intel vs AMD)?
I do computing with one fortran program and I have two machines:

one with an Intel Xeon E5-2670 (Linux Mint 21.2 x86_64, Kernel: 5.15.0-86-generic)
and the other with an AMD 7700X (Linux Mint 21.3 x86_64, Kernel: 6.5.0-35-generic).

I compile the same program on the same gcc compiler version 11.4.0 (gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0) with the same flags (FFLAGS = -O0 -g, but with other flags the problem remains), but my results on these computers always diverge, and systematically, some arrays of results coincide, but most do not. Regardless of the digit capacity of the number (...E+04 or E-03), the last few digits differ in many arrays.
The command gcc -Q -v /dev/null output is the same for both machines:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' 
--with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 
--prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only 
--program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- 
--enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib 
--without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib 
--enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug 
--enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new 
--enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie 
--with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto 
--enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet 
--with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 
--enable-multilib --with-tune=generic 
--enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr 
--without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu 
--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu 
--with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd

The Intel machine has DDR3 with ECC support, but I think this is clearly not the problem, I changed the BIOS settings (Patrol Scrub, Demand Scrub), but the results did not change.
What could be the reason for the difference in the calculation results and how can I try to remove it? I want to achieve a reproduction of the result, I'm trying to migrate my work to a more modern AMD machine.
UPD: as recommended to me, I moved the executable built on Intel to an AMD machine and launched it there, and got a new result that does not match either Intel or previous AMD results.

Did you try the very same executable on both machines? The CPU difference may be a red herring. I do not think anyone will be able to tell anything definitive without the code.

Thanks for the answer! I moved the executable built on Intel to an AMD machine and launched it there, and got a new result that does not match either Intel or previous AMD results.

Build your code with maximum debugging turned on.  Use -fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=invalid,overflow -freal-init=nan.  It may also be profitable to address any warnings that appear with -Wall -Werror

Has any numerical analysis  been done onthe code? Do you know how sensitive to round off error or similar it is?

Generally speaking, bit to bit reproduction of floating point computations is never guaranteed when changing any element of the toolchain, compiler (even compiler version), options, CPU model... It's not impossible that in addition you have a bug in your code that behaves differently on different machines, but it's impossible to tell from your post... But as long as the differences are limited to the last digits I would bet these are expected differences.

Thanks to everyone for their comments, I read everything carefully and now I’m trying to fix the errors that appeared after building with -fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=invalid,overflow  -Wall  -Werror flags.
Interestingly, the GCC could not accept the -freal-init=nan flag.

@IanBush, I am not the author of this code, but I am ready to try to do such an analysis. Could you explain what exactly can be done in this case, what I can read, or where to start?

I gave a presentation on this very topic at Supercomputing '13. You can find the slides at https://sc13.supercomputing.org/sites/default/files/WorkshopsArchive/pdfs/wp129s1.pdf  The upshot is that you generally can't eliminate floating point value inconsistencies when changing environments. My presentation focused on using Intel compilers, but it applies to almost any compiler.
There may be things you can to do reduce differences, but insisting on eliminating all of them is likely to be a hopeless task.

Thank you very much for your answer, I will carefully read your presentation. I'm currently working on researching this code and will definitely write about my results.
